# How should i return an object from a conversion function if the class of the returned object is defined later?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, return-type, data-conversion

```
class time24;
class time12
{
operator time24()
 {
  ...
  return time24(temp)   // error
 }
}

class time24
{
 ...
};
```

error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'time24'

how else can i return the object to overcome this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You move the implementation after the class definitions, in an implementation file:

```
//header.h
class time24;
class time12
{
    operator time24();
}

class time24
{
 ...
};

//implementation.cpp
#include "header.h"
time12::operator time24()
{
   return time24(temp)   // error
}
```

I'm assuming you meant to implement `operator time24()`.